# Was / Were. What to use after Poetry?

Tags: sentence, passive-voice

I was solving a question paper of English.

There was a question to fill in the blank using passive voice:-

**Poetry *(i)*___ (write) and dramas *(ii)*___ (composed).**

I knew that

***(ii)***  is  : were, As dramas **are** composed.

But Poetry **is** written ,So *(i)* must be **was**.

So the sentence is :

***Poetry was written and dramas were composed***.

And this seems a bit awkward to me..

Am i correct or is it **was**?

Edit: ***Using past is mandatory!***

Comment: What makes you think you need any verb in the past? To me a simple "Poetry is written and dramas are composed" works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poetry is an uncountable noun and drama a countable one.

So, **Poetry is written and dramas are composed.**

**Poetry was written and dramas were composed.** Both are right.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it refers to *generic* poetry and dramas, I see nothing wrong with the use of present tense - it's about the way either is 'produced'.

It would be different if the text hinted at a particular piece of poetry or drama written/composed in the past: there of course the past tense would be mandatory.

Comment: Oh i forgot to tell past is mandatory!!